# Need to access image for selected item in android gridview

Tags: android-widget

I want to access the properties of an image when it is selected from a gridview.  For example  if I am using.

```
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.imageGallery);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id)
    {
         //need code in here that I can do something like this.
         //Get access to the integer value of the R.drawable.myimage
         //use that int too do a lookup in a dictionary to check for existance
         //can't see to find any code to get at the drawable associated with the image clicked in the grid, did intense debug
```

And data not easily visible at runtime

```
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

@Reid I think you will want to create a custom adapter (extend BaseAdapter or other) that holds a  view class containing the metadata you need to get at, based on the position in the list.  Possibly an easier way, but that is what I did in a ListView..  A couple of links:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html
http://www.anddev.org/gridview-t5585.html